# mgcv error: "x has insufficient unique values to support 3 knots: reduce k"

Tags: r, regression, spline, gam, mgcv

I am trying to fit the following GAM model

```
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", k = 2), family = betar(link = "logit"), data = d)
```

where `x` can take only two unique values.

However, when I run the model I get the following error

```
Error in smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  x has insufficient unique values to support 3 knots: reduce k.
In addition: Warning message:
In smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
  basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible
```

As the error message shows, the number of knots is automatically set to 3 (even if I have specified `k = 2` in the `gam` call).

Is there any reason why I cannot have only 2 knots? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you define a cubic polynomial (uniquely) on just two points? A cubic polynomial `s(x)` needs 4 coefficients, that is, as least 4 unique `x` values. `mgcv` applies centering constraint on `s(x)` so one fewer coefficient is needed, but you still need 3.

If your covariate just has two unique values, you can at most fit it with a straight line:

```
gam(y ~ x, family = betar(link = "logit"), data = d)
```